# Error to find inherited function method when summarising PCA

Tags: r

I don't understand why I am having the `Error(function(classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function 'Summary' for signature '"prcomp"'`.

I have checked through my code and the packages and everything looks very much okay.

[image: 1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sms76.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

One needs to use lower case `summary`. The code has capital S in `Summary`